# document.referrer is not empty on the first visit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, referrer

When I visit https://www.oxyhealth.com/ website on a new Chrome tab, I sometimes notice a strange behavior.

Sometimes when I type `document.referrer` in the Chrome console for that tab, it outputs `"https://www.oxyhealth.com/"` instead of `""`:

[image]

It doesn't always happen, but it happens often enough (which disrupts the behavior of one of the website's scripts).

Why does this occur?
Can it be helped?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There might be a script defining it manually. Did you check?

Comment: @Zenoo I couldn’t find anything... plus, I tried to change document.referrer programmatically, and I don’t think it’s posdiv